# R : Adding a variable to a barplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my problem.
I've produced data using diplyr,presented in a table, like this:

```
# A tibble: 216 x 4
sample proto virus                     prop
<chr>  <chr> <chr>                    <dbl>
1 HSV    E     Mastadenovirus      0.00000770
2 HSV    E     Orthopneumovirus    0         
3 HSV    E     Simplexvirus        0.996     
4 HSV    E     Alphainfluenzavirus 0         
5 HSV    E     Enterovirus         0         
6 HSV    E     Dependoparvovirus   0         
7 HSV    E     Levivirus           0.0000847 
8 HSV    E     others              0.00373   
9 HSV    E     Mastadenovirus      0.0000136 
10 HSV    E     Orthopneumovirus    0         
# ... with 206 more rows
```

I'm trying to produce a barplot graph using ggplot2 currently looking like this:[current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3G2h.png). However, this graph is not complete, because I want to draw proportion for each virus (done) in each sample (done), but depending on the other variable proto, like that:[final plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8evdQ.png) But I dont really know how to proceed.

here is my simple code for the current plot:

```
ggplot(test, aes(fill=virus,x=sample, y=prop))+
geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

Should I rework my data or I'm just simply missing something?

Thx and have a nice day.

EDIT:
Can I push a bit more?

I just figured out that one data is missing in my table: a "dupli" column.

```
    # A tibble: 216 x 5
   sample proto dupli virus                     prop
   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 HSV    E     S3    Mastadenovirus      0.00000770
 2 HSV    E     S3    Orthopneumovirus    0         
 3 HSV    E     S3    Simplexvirus        0.996     
 4 HSV    E     S3    Alphainfluenzavirus 0         
 5 HSV    E     S3    Enterovirus         0         
 6 HSV    E     S3    Dependoparvovirus   0         
 7 HSV    E     S3    Levivirus           0.0000847 
 8 HSV    E     S3    others              0.00373   
 9 HSV    E     S10   Mastadenovirus      0.0000136 
10 HSV    E     S10   Orthopneumovirus    0
```

these data was important to draw the proportion for each virus (done), in each sample (done ) for each proto (done), in each dupli(to do)?

how should I edit my code below:

```
ggplot(test, aes(fill=virus,x=proto, y=prop,))+ 
geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
facet_grid(.~sample)
```

Comment: You could try `ggplot(test, aes(fill=virus,x=proto, y=prop))+ geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + facet_grid(.~sample)`

Comment: Well it work perfectly! Thank you:)

Comment: Just figured out some informations was missing in my post, question edited.